# How to print a fixed length memory area which contains multiple \0?

Tags: c

I have a memory area with fixed length.

```
char *p = malloc(100);
memset(p, 0 ,100);
```

I have some strings in this memory area, along with some \0, for example

```
memcpy(p, "asdf", 4);
memcpy(p + 10, "ghi", 3);
memcpy(p + 20, "1234", 3);
```

So, there are \0 between `asdf` and `ghi`

I want to print this memory are and the output is

```
asdfghi1234
```

How can I do that? Note that above code is just an example, where are these \0 is not fixed.

Comment: Do you want to write the 0 bytes to stdout, or skip them?

Comment: It's ok to just skip it.

Comment: But is it also okay to not skip them? Because that’s easier :)

Comment: Yeah, it does not matter, as long as it doesn't mess up the screen(stdout).

Comment: let me try, one line without loop is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the NUL bytes don’t mess up the way the text appears (I think) and that’s all you’re looking for, you should be able to write all of the bytes directly to stdout:

```
fwrite(p, sizeof(char), 100, stdout);
```

Comment: Redirecting `stdout` to a file, will write 100 bytes to the file, including all the `'\0'`s.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the size of the block of memory (hard coded to 100 here):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    char c = p[i];
    if (c != 0)
        printf("%c", c);
}
```

Minor nit but in your sample above, the string will be "asdfghi123", because the memcpy for "1234" is only copying 3 bytes.